# Milo ExtensionObject to CustomClass

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, milo

Is there an example to convert an ExtensionObject to CustomClass (in Camel - Milo) that can be used in SpringBoot?

```
routeBuilder.from(getUriFrom("ns=4;s=GV_PcHmi.tPcHmi.tPlcToPcHmiSta.atAlarm", 1000))
                        .process((Exchange exchange) -> {                                                
                            DataValue data = exchange.getIn().getBody(DataValue.class);

                            if( data.getStatusCode().isGood() )
                            {
                               ExtensionObject[] value = (ExtensionObject[]) data.getValue().getValue();

                               for( ExtensionObject x : xo )
                               {
                                  CONVERSION ???
                               }
                           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would call `decode()` on the ExtensionObject.

See this example: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/6548e3fcaef35de558c913962069c786db67b4b2/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client/UnifiedAutomationReadCustomDataTypeExample.java#L51-L55

To decode custom datatypes the server must be exposing an OPC UA 1.03 DataType Dictionary that defines all of the custom types.

Comment: How can I get the reference to OpcUaClient from camel?

Comment: I don’t know, I’m not involved with the camel project at all.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I keep looking on camel